# +[AVCaptureDevice initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called

Tags: python, audio, video, multiprocessing

I have 2 functions

```
def record_save():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Say something ")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        print("Done ")
        with open("audio.wav", "wb") as f:
            f.write(audio.get_wav_data())

    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said :", text)
    except Exception as error:
        print("Could not recognize what you said")
        print(error)
    pass
```

This function is to get the audio from the mic and store it in a `.wav` file. It also stores the audio transcription in a variable text

```
def listen_to_speaker():

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
            out.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
    pass
```

This uses `OpenCV` to record and store a video in a `.avi` file.

I used multiprocessing in order to run the two processes simultaneously, like so:

```
    t1 = Process(target=listen_to_speaker)
    t1.start()
    t2 = Process(target=record_save)
    t2.start()
```

I get the following error message:

> objc[6742]: +[AVCaptureDevice initialize] may have been in progress in
>   another thread when fork() was called.
>
> We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process.
>
> Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.

I want to be able to run these 2 functions simultaneously in order to record an audio and video that correspond to each other. Currently, first the audio is recorded and saved, and then the webcam turns on to record the video.

I have also tried adding
`export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`
to the end of the file after running `nano .bash_profile`, but I get the same error

I tried `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES python3 my-program.py` as well, but to no avail

Comment: maybe you have to only wait awhile before you run second proces.

Comment: in this answer they use `cv` for video but `pyaudio` for audio [How to capture a video (AND audio) in python, from a camera (or webcam)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140495/how-to-capture-a-video-and-audio-in-python-from-a-camera-or-webcam)